# SQL query to mark tasks done from a specific user

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my tables:

Table tasks

```
id  label
----------
1   Task 1
2   Task 2
3   Task 3
4   Task 4
5   Task 5
6   Task 6
7   Task 7
7   Task 8
```

Table user_tasks

```
id id_user id_task
------------------
1     1      1
2     1      2
3     1      4
4     2      1
5     3      1
```

I have this query which I thought was working:

```
SELECT t.id, t.label as text, IF(u.id_user IS NULL, 0, 1) as done
            FROM tasks AS t
            LEFT JOIN user_tasks AS u ON t.id = u.id_task
            WHERE u.id_user = 1
               OR u.id_user IS NULL
            ORDER BY id DESC
```

So if I run that query, I get this successful response:

```
id  text    done
----------------
8   Task 8  0
7   Task 7  0
6   Task 6  0
5   Task 5  0
4   Task 4  1
3   Task 3  0
2   Task 2  1
1   Task 1  1
```

But if I put another user ID that doesn't have any task yet completed, like for example 5 I get this result:

```
id  text    done
----------------
8   Task 8  0
7   Task 7  0
6   Task 6  0
5   Task 5  0
3   Task 3  0
```

So all the tasks, minus the ones that are already set for a different user on the user_tasks table.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: MySql, i didn't read the sql-server description where it specified it was MS only. I removed it. Sorry about that

Comment: If you move `u.id_user = 1` to the `ON` clause, you can remove the `WHERE` clause (including `u.id_user IS NULL`.)

Comment: wow... can't believe I didn't see that. Want to make that into a proper answer so I can select it? Thanks!

Comment: So you get the correct answer now?

Comment: yes, but I can't choose a comment as a correct answer :) I did upvote it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `u.id_user = 1` to the `ON` clause, and remove the `WHERE` clause (including `u.id_user IS NULL`.)

```
SELECT t.id, t.label as text, IF(u.id_user IS NULL, 0, 1) as done
FROM tasks AS t
    LEFT JOIN user_tasks AS u ON t.id = u.id_task AND u.id_user = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even read the problem description, just spotted that the condition wasn't placed properly.